# Perl eval or do return scalar?

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl... could someone help me understand why perl eval behave like this:

eval with array or list: pass

eval with list + or do: pass

eval with array + or do: return value is not the expected result, it's taking the last element.

```
80> eval{(1,2,3)} or do {}
Useless use of a constant (2) in void context at reply input line 1.
$res[34] = 3

81> eval{[1,2,3]} or do {}
$res[35] = [
  1,
  2,
  3
]

82> eval{(1,2,3)}
$res[36] = [
  1,
  2,
  3
]

83> eval{[1,2,3]}
$res[37] = [
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The code snippets in the question seem to run in [Reply](https://metacpan.org/dist/Reply/view/bin/reply) (a REPL shell), so in list context.

Let's start from claryfing the [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context) aspect of this, a crucial concept in Perl.  From [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval)

> In both forms, the value returned is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the mini-program; a return statement may also be used, just as with subroutines. The expression providing the return value is evaluated in void, scalar, or list context, depending on the context of the `eval` itself.

So if the return of `eval` is assigned to a scalar then the (last) expression in the block is evaluated in the scalar context.  If the `eval` is `or`-ed (with the return of the `do`block for example, like here), it is scalar context again.

In such a case the [comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) behaves as

> In scalar context it evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right argument and returns that value.

While `comma` is evaluating and throwing values away it acts in void context (those values aren't used for anything), and those are the warnings we see:

```
perl -wE'$val = eval { (7, 8, 9) }'
```

prints

```
Useless use of a constant (7) in void context at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant (8) in void context at -e line 1.
```

since the first two values are discarded while the last one does get used. Same for

```
perl -wE'eval { (7, 8, 9) } or do { 1 }'
```

and for the same reason, as `9` gets `or`-ed with the return value of `do`.

If nothing at all were to be done with this

```
perl -wE'eval { (7, 8, 9) }'
```

then we would get

```
Useless use of a constant (7) in void context at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant (8) in void context at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant (9) in void context at -e line 1.
```

(But in the environment used in the question, which is a REPL shell, this gets assigned to an array, unlike the snippet from a one-liner above. Such list context is discussed next.)

So these warnings are from the `comma` operator, while the context for its behavior is supplied by the context the `eval` is in.

Now, if the `eval`'s return is used in a list context, like passed to a `map` or assigned to an array, like it is in the environment used in the question, then the list context inside the block makes the `comma` behave as

> In list context, it's just the list argument separator, and inserts both its arguments into the list.

So that list (`7, 8, 9`) gets orderly returned and there are no warnings.

There is one more case to clarify, with `[7, 8, 9]` -- now the `[ ]` are the constructor for an anonymous array so the `comma` operator inside is in the list context and "*inserts*" its arguments into the list, which is used to build an array ref.  No reasons for warnings.

---

The fun part: when `1` is an element of the list there is *no* warning about it being a useless constant etc!  Like, for

```
perl -wE'eval { (7, 1, 9) }'
```

we get

```
Useless use of a constant (7) in void context at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant (9) in void context at -e line 1.
```

The reason being that `1` is (apparently) special-cased this way so that one can do things like

```
1 while ...
```

---

Thanks for Dave Mitchell for letting me know about why `1` is excluded from warnings.

Thanks to ikegami for informing about debugger/REPL and its list context.

Comment: 1 doesn't warn so you can write code like: '1 while ....'

Comment: @DaveMitchell Ah!! Thank you.  Curious how I never questioned why we may do `1 while...`

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you.  I thought that at first but then my debugger sessions look different (and I don't use it much).  Adjusted text accordingly, at just a few places

Comment: yeah, I suppose you're right. But it's obviously an REPL that evaluates in list context, just like the Perl debugger

Comment: Also useful for `-e1`. `0` is similarly excluded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start by studying Perl's concept of [context](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558).

The short version is that operators are evaluated in list, scalar or void context. The context of an operator is determined by the operator of which it is an operand.

In list context, an operator may return any number (0 or more) scalars.

In scalar context, an operator must return *exactly* one scalar (no more, no less).

In void context, the scalars returned by an operator are discarded.

Operators can and do and return different values depending on the context. Any operator that nominally returns multiple scalars must necessarily return something different in list context and scalar context.

---

Now that you've studied Perl's concept of context, I'll cover how it applies to the list/comma operator.

To do that, we'll look at these two statements.

```perl
my @a = (1,2,3);
my $s = (1,2,3);
```

Note that all `( )` does is change precedence like `( )` in mathematics. It doesn't result in any code. It doesn't create any kind of data structure.

In the first case, we have a list assignment operator. It evaluates its right-hand side operand in list context. This means that `1,2,3` is evaluated in list context.

In list context, `1,2,3` evaluates each item of the list in list context, and returns every scalar produced. As such, it returns `1`, `2` and `3`.

In the second case, we have a scalar assignment operator. It evaluates its left-hand side operand in scalar context. This means that `1,2,3` is evaluated in scalar context.

In scalar context, `1,2,3` evaluates each item but the last in void context, then evaluates the last item in scalar context, and returns the scalar produced by the last time. As such, it's effectively short for `do { 1;2;3 }`, and it returns `3`.

---

Finally, let's examine the context of each operator in the expressions you provided.

The perl debugger evaluates provided code in list context.

`or` imposes a scalar context on its left-hand side operand.

`[ ]` evaluates its initializaing expression in list context.

`eval` propagates its context to the last statement of the block.

```perl
eval{(1,2,3)} or do {}

# Order   Context   Operator        Produces
# -----   -------   -------------   --------
# 6       list      or              3
# 5       scalar       eval         3
# 4       scalar          ,         3
# 1       void               1      <nothing>
# 2       void               2      <nothing>
# 3       scalar             3      3
# -       list         do           <not evaluated>
```

```perl
eval{[1,2,3]} or do {}

# Order   Context   Operator        Produces
# -----   -------   -------------   --------
# 7       list      or              ref to array
# 6       scalar       eval         ref to array
# 5       scalar          []        ref to array
# 4       list               ,      1 and 2 and 3
# 1       list                  1   1      
# 2       list                  2   2
# 3       list                  3   3
# -       list         do           <not evaluated>
```

```perl
eval{(1,2,3)}

# Order   Context   Operator        Produces
# -----   -------   -------------   --------
# 5       list      eval            1 and 2 and 3
# 4       list         ,            1 and 2 and 3
# 1       list            1         1      
# 2       list            2         2
# 3       list            3         3
```

```perl
eval{[1,2,3]}

# Order   Context   Operator        Produces
# -----   -------   -------------   --------
# 6       list      eval            ref to array
# 5       list         []           ref to array
# 4       list            ,         1 and 2 and 3
# 1       list               1      1      
# 2       list               2      2
# 3       list               3      3
```